# SonarQube Configuration Issue

Tags: c#, .net-core, sonarqube

In my Jenkins Pipeline, I have this stage:

```
    stage('SonarQube analysis') {
        steps { 
            withSonarQubeEnv('Sonar Env') {
                sh "dotnet '/usr/local/sonar-scanner-msbuild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll' begin /k:${SONARQUBEPROJECTKEY} /v:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
                sh "dotnet build 'src/hub-backend.sln'"
                sh "dotnet '/usr/local/sonar-scanner-msbuild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll' end"
            }
        }
    }
```

When I got to the Sonarqube reporting site, I see the build there, the code files, the updated lines.

However, I do not see the quality analysis, the code coverage, bugs, etc.

What am I missing? Can somebody point me to the documentation on how to properly configure?

### Update

Using the SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins Plugin version 2.9.

I've also excluded the Test project from being scanned and that is noted by the scanner:

*The exclude flag has been set so the project will not be analyzed by SonarQube. Project file: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HubPipeline-Backend/workspace/src/WebServer.Tests/WebServer.Tests.csproj*

Also, here is a warning that I am not sure why it is even considered for scanning:

_WARNING: File '/var/lib/jenkins/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.azurekeyvault.hostingstartup/2.0.4/contentFiles/cs/netstandard2.0/*AssembyInfo.KeyVaultHostingStartup.cs' is not located under the root directory '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HubPipeline-Backend/workspace/src' and will not be analyzed.*

SQ Web site: Version 6.7.6 (build 38781)

Comment: Any errors/warnings in the SonarQube log? Which version/plugins do you use?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I've added what I was able to find under 'update' in the original post. Thanks.

Comment: @JeroenHeier this is the only entry I have in my pipeline. Is there some other 'thing' that I have to do to run the default quality gate?

Comment: The SonarScanner instructions can be found [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/) and importing the coverage results can be found [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/). SonarQube does not generate the coverage results itself; it uses the results generated during the analysis. Not running unittest results in no coverage.